Dynamic IP keeps on getting blacklist
Problem started when our emails stop going out from my Microsoft outlook, then I checked my public IP, and checked that IP on mxbox and other blacklist websites , my IP keeps on different blacklist rdl
Our router is set to dynamic IP
What is the solution?
Our domain is hosted on shared server at HostGator and cdn applied via cloud flare
Shall I use static IP from my ISP? Will it resolve the issue
Note. I have check all systems of my office no malware or virus found
But our IP keeps on getting blacklisted on spamhaus and other spamming related rbls
Any suggestions

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your domain and your local computer are different things. In what way are they associated with each other for the purposes of outgoing email?

https://www.f-secure.com/en/online-scanner
